# Difference between "become" and "make"

Tags: meaning

Please explain the difference between "He will become a good lawyer" and "He will make a good lawyer."

Comment: _He will become a good lawyer_ = He can be expected to develop into a good lawyer in the future (perhaps when he has had more experience). _He will make a good lawyer_ = (said of someone who plans to become one) He is the kind of person who will probably be a good lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

Both work in the case of a talented law student, but consider:

If someone is studying law and show early signs of talent, you can say they will become a good lawyer.

If a motorist is arguing with the police about some traffic infringement and is correct in proving no rules were broken, you can say he/she will make a good lawyer because they have a talent for legal matters.  You compare and imagine that person would be good at that job, yet there is no real possibility.